# Outlook ribbon button functions not loading

Tags: outlook, office365

In an add-in for Outlook I'm working on I'm trying to add a ribbon button that executes a function on the add-in (a module extension).

I've followed the instructions as per the documentation and create a largely empty `functionfile.html` with the javascript functions, and referenced this in the manifest.

The functions don't fire however, and there is no error whatsoever. I've found a [sample on Github that does work](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/master/docs/outlook/extension-module-outlook-add-ins.md).

1. When I copy the manifest from Github and change the url and function names, it does not work for me either.
2. In a task-pane add-in rather than a Module Extension it works fine, so it is not my html/js code either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it would help to have your code to see what's wrong I might have a solution regardless (depending on whether what you're experiencing is what I've experienced before). Somehow, the module extension and function executing buttons on the ribbon do not work together when the functions are in an html document that is NOT the default in a folder on a server. In other words, the url to a functionfile must end with '/' instead of 'functionfile.html'. This makes little sense but simply including your functions in the index.html of your module extension and using the same url for both the module extension and function file is the easiest solution.

It definitely seems like a bug however.